# Getting different response From an API when tried from POSTMAN and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire, postman

I am trying hit an `GET` API with a Authorization header but getting different response:

From swift:

```
  {
        error = "access_denied";
        "error_description" = "OAuth2 authentication required";
    }
```

swift:

```
var urlString = "http://exaple.com/ser/2521"
            urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
            let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.oAuthToken.access_token!
                , "Accept": "application/json"
            ]
Alamofire.request(url!, method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers) .responseJSON { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    guard let response =  data as? [String: Any] else {
                        return
                    }
                    print(response)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)

                }
            }
```

From POSTMAN:

Response is:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Reservation failed."
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you are calling the service providing same data, but getting different result, you should debug the api code...

Comment: i have used the same swift code generated by postman...but postman swift code  shows different result in xcode..

Comment: finally got the reason: it due to redirecting at the backend

Comment: When you say redireacting at backend, what do you mean